# Values of Body Hydration Values to calibrate the readings of Galvanic skin response sensor

Tags: hydration, body-mass-index-bmi

I am trying to make a circuit to implement a Galvanic skin response sensor to measure the skin resistance and then use it to find the skin conductance. Then, I wish to calibrate these readings with some standard data so that the actual body hydration level can be calculated.
In order to do so, I used one of the reference designs of Texas Instruments ([Link](http://www.ti.com/tool/TIDM-BIOSIGNMONITOR)). (The discussion related to this project is running on another TI forum with the link [HERE](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/p/760267/2846858#2846858).) 
The final circuit has been pasted below.
[image] 
The circuit has been implemented using hardware and I am getting voltage values from the op amp output terminal.
The problem arises when I cannot compare these values with some standard data that is used in the Clinical labs for measuring body hydration level. So, the voltage values that I get cannot help in finding whether the person's body hydration level is high/low/some xyz value.

I need to calibrate these readings with some standard data so that the actual body hydration level can be calculated. 
Where can I get the standard data that I use for the calibration? OR is there some alternative approach to calibrate my readings?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Where can I get the standard data that I use for the calibration?` -- What "standard data" are you asking for? Your question is entirely unclear.

Comment: He is looking for standard data against which to compare his readings, voltage levels. I thought it was clear, I just don't know the answer, or whether there is an answer.

Comment: @De Novo, thanks for restating my query better... As you already mentioned, to calibrate my readings against standard voltage values is one approach that I have taken up ...but I am open to any other approach.

Comment: This might be worth posting on the electrical engineering Stack Exchange, but I don't think it's off topic here either.

Comment: @Chris, you might be surprised to know that I have copied this exact question from there ( it was posted by me) here as it was listed as off topic and I was rewarded with -2 points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skin becomes a better conductor of electricity in response to physiologically arousing stimuli which can be external or internal. Increased sweat increases skin conductivity. This is known as the Skin Conductance Response (SCR) - also known as the Galvanic Skin Response (GSR). (See [this Massachusetts Institute of Technology faq page](https://www.media.mit.edu/galvactivator/faq.html)).

Another name for GSR is [Electrodermal Activity (EDA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodermal_activity) and EDA measurement is one component of modern polygraph devices, which are often used as lie detectors (Source: [BIOPAC Systems, Inc.](https://www.biopac.com/curriculum/l09-eda-polygraph)).

Bearing this in mind, even though Microsoft submitted a patent application for such a device in 2015 ([full technical details here](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20160374588)), galvanic skin response sensors cannot be deemed reliable to determine body hydration levels.  **There can be no standard voltage levels** because [different people sweat at different rates](https://www.menshealth.com/fitness/a19520755/what-determines-how-much-you-sweat).  Look at [hyperhidrosis](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/excessive-sweating-hyperhidrosis) sufferers for example.

**Estimations** of hydration levels can be made however, **if other data is combined with galvanic skin response results** — body mass index, heart rate and skin temperature ([Suryadevara et al., 2015](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sc_Mukhopadhyay/publication/272519591_Towards_a_Smart_Non-Invasive_Fluid_Loss_Measurement_System/links/55a7474808ae51639c576f71.pdf)).

### References

Suryadevara, N. K., Mukhopadhyay, S. C., & Barrack, L. (2015). Towards a smart non-invasive fluid loss measurement system. *Journal of medical systems, 39*(4), 38. doi: [10.1007/s10916-015-0206-6](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10916-015-0206-6)

Comment: This is interesting, and perhaps useful information for the OP, but it doesn't seem to directly address his question, which is "where can I find/are there standard voltage levels"

Comment: @DeNovo - There can be no *standard* voltage levels.  Edited to reflect that and thanks for highlighting that.

Comment: @Chris Roger, thank you for this informative answer. Although this might not suffice this question, it is as good as the answer. I have concluded that as the exact Hydration level of body cannot be determined using this, I can surely get the variation in that, which will be almost as helpful in my case. Thank you once again.